# Adobe AEM 6.4.x: How to restrict which components can be added on the page (using static templates)?

Tags: aem, aem-6

We have a need to restrict certain authors access to components.

**example:** The restricted authors can only add the image and rich text editor components on the page.

The only thing I can think of is denying access to the component (e.g. /apps/myapps/component/xxx).

**additional info:**

- We're using static templates.
- restrictions will be applied to a group and then the group will then be given to the restricted users. Currently using Netcentric ACLs to manage this.

Any ideas on how to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be solved with ACLs.
The only way might be to intercept the request to

```
/etc/designs/YOUR-PROJECT/DESIGNFILE/_jcr_content.json/
```

And then manipulate the json structure based on the current user's groups.

Although this will solve the problem, I do not like this kind of solution at all...

HTH anyway.